# Gathering segments of 2D arrays with MPI in FORTRAN

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, mpi

I have a code which follows particles and outputs the particles at N timeslices.  So what I have in the end is an array TEMP(1:M,0:N) where M is the total number of particles.  Now the problem is easily made parallel by dividing up the particles.  So each processor does work on an array TEMP(MYSTART:MYEND,0:N), while the master does it's work in TEMP(1:M,0:N).  Now I need to recombine the array (there are actually multiple arrays like this but focus on one for now).  Using a SENDV-RECV loop I coded up:

```
  IF (myid == master) THEN
     ALLOCATE(B_lines(1:nlines,0:nsteps),...
  ELSE
     ALLOCATE(B_lines(mystart:myend,0:nsteps),...
  END IF

  CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_FIELDLINES,ierr_mpi)
  IF (ierr_mpi /=0) CALL andle_err(MPI_BARRIER_ERR,'fieldlines_init',ierr_mpi)
  IF (myid == master) THEN
     ALLOCATE(buffer_mast(4,0:nsteps))
     DO i = myend+1, nlines
        CALL MPI_RECV(buffer_mast,4*(nsteps+1),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
                      MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_FIELDLINES,status,ierr_mpi)
        IF (ierr_mpi /=0) CALL handle_err(MPI_RECV_ERR,'fieldlines_init_mgrid',ierr_mpi)
        sender = status(MPI_SOURCE)
        j      = status(MPI_TAG)
        R_lines(j,:)   = buffer_mast(1,:) 
        Z_lines(j,:)   = buffer_mast(2,:)
        PHI_lines(j,:) = buffer_mast(3,:)
        B_lines(j,:)   = buffer_mast(4,:)
     END DO
     DEALLOCATE(buffer_mast)
  ELSE
     IF (mystart <= nlines) THEN
        ALLOCATE(buffer_slav(4,0:nsteps))
        DO j = mystart, myend
           buffer_slav(1,:) = R_lines(j,:)
           buffer_slav(2,:) = Z_lines(j,:)
           buffer_slav(3,:) = PHI_lines(j,:)
           buffer_slav(4,:) = B_lines(j,:)
           CALL MPI_SEND(buffer_slav,4*(nsteps+1),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,master,j,MPI_COMM_FIELDLINES,ierr_mpi)
           IF (ierr_mpi /=0) CALL handle_err(MPI_SEND_ERR,'fieldlines_init_mgrid',ierr_mpi)
        END DO
        DEALLOCATE(buffer_slav)
     END IF
  END IF
```

Now this works just fine but scales poorly.  Even with only 64 cores the code spends a great deal of time just sending the data back and forth.  Now I'd like to take advantage of GATHERV.  So I created a subroutine which I call like:

```
CALL FIELDLINES_TRANSMIT_2DDBL(mystart,myend,0,nsteps,B_lines(mystart:myend,0:nsteps),&
                          numprocs,mnum,moffsets,myid,master,MPI_COMM_FIELDLINES,ier)
```

And looks like:

```
SUBROUTINE FIELDLINES_TRANSMIT_2DDBL(n1,n2,m1,m2,data_in,nproc,mnum,moffsets,id,root,COMM_local,ier)
USE stel_kinds, ONLY: rprec
IMPLICIT NONE
INCLUDE 'mpif.h' ! MPI
INTEGER, INTENT(in)           :: n1,n2,m1,m2,nproc,id,root,COMM_local
INTEGER, INTENT(in)           :: mnum(nproc), moffsets(nproc)
REAL(rprec), INTENT(inout)    :: data_in(n1:n2,m1:m2)
INTEGER, INTENT(inout)        :: ier
INTEGER, PARAMETER            :: ndims=2
INTEGER, PARAMETER            :: sstart(2) = (/0,0/) ! Starting offsets
INTEGER                       :: dbl_size, localsize, ARRAY_SEND_TYPE, RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE
INTEGER                       :: asize(ndims), ssize(ndims), mrec(nproc)
INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND):: low_bound,extent
DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE :: buffer_temp(:,:)

IF (ier <0) RETURN
mrec = 1
ssize(1) = n2-n1+1
ssize(2) = m2-m1+1
localsize = mnum(id+1) 
ALLOCATE(buffer_temp(ssize(1),ssize(2)))
buffer_temp(1:ssize(1),1:ssize(2)) = data_in(n1:n2,m1:m2)
asize    = ssize
CALL MPI_BCAST(asize, 2, MPI_INTEGER, root, COMM_local, ier)
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(ndims,asize,ssize,sstart,MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN,&
                              MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier)
CALL MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dbl_size,ier)
low_bound = 0
extent = dbl_size
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,low_bound,extent,RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier)
IF (id == root) THEN
   localsize = PRODUCT(ssize)
   mrec(1)   = localsize
   CALL MPI_GATHERV(MPI_IN_PLACE,1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
                    data_in,mrec, moffsets,RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,&
                    root,COMM_local,ier)
ELSE
   CALL MPI_GATHERV(buffer_temp,localsize,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
                    buffer_temp,mrec, moffsets,RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,&
                    root,COMM_local,ier)
END IF
CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier); IF (ier <0) RETURN
CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(RESIZED_ARRAY_SEND_TYPE,ier); IF (ier <0) RETURN
DEALLOCATE(buffer_temp)
ier = 0
CALL MPI_BARRIER(COMM_local, ier)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE FIELDLINES_TRANSMIT_2DDBL
```

Now I had another code which had opposite indexing (0:nsteps,1:nlines) and it appears to work just fine, but when I try to pass the arrays indexed (1:nlines,0:nsteps) the resulting array appears to all messed up.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I need the array sizes to be arbitrary solutions where all processors need to have the same array size won't work for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found a memory hungry way to do this.  Basically I put everything is globally sized arrays and use `MPI_REDUCE`.  This is much faster than my old queue system but at the cost of memory.  Here's the code

```
SUBROUTINE TRANSMIT_2DDBL(n1,n2,m1,m2,data_in,n1_gbl,n2_gbl,id,root,COMM_local,ier)
IMPLICIT NONE
INCLUDE 'mpif.h' ! MPI
INTEGER, INTENT(in)           :: n1,n2,m1,m2,id,root,COMM_local
INTEGER, INTENT(in)           :: n1_gbl, n2_gbl
DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(inout)    :: data_in(n1:n2,m1:m2)
INTEGER, INTENT(inout)        :: ier
INTEGER                       :: nt_gbl
DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE :: buffer_temp(:,:)

IF (ier <0) RETURN
nt_gbl=(n2_gbl-n1_gbl+1)*(m2-m1+1)
ALLOCATE(buffer_temp(n1_gbl:n2_gbl,m1:m2))
buffer_temp = 0
buffer_temp(n1:n2,m1:m2) = data_in(n1:n2,m1:m2)
IF (id == root) THEN
   CALL MPI_REDUCE(MPI_IN_PLACE,buffer_temp,nt_gbl,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,&
                   root,COMM_local,ier)
   data_in = buffer_temp
ELSE
     CALL MPI_REDUCE(buffer_temp,buffer_temp,nt_gbl,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,&
                  root,COMM_local,ier)
END IF
DEALLOCATE(buffer_temp)
ier = 0
CALL MPI_BARRIER(COMM_local, ier)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE TRANSMIT_2DDBL
```

Of course the root process needs to pass n1_gbl and n2_gbl as n1 and n2 respectively before entering.  But it seems to improve performance for me.

Comment: It should be possible to do this more memory efficiently with subarryays or vectors. However, I think I misunderstood your initial code. In the text, you imply that m1 and m2 are equal to 0 and nsteps on all processes, but here it looks like they could be different on all processes. Could you clarify?

Comment: In my case n1 and n2 are different on all processors, and n2-n1 is also different.  m1 and m2 are same in my case but I'd like a solution which doesn't rely on m1 and m2 being the same between all processors.  I think the problem is that the GATHER and GATHERV statements require that the type be the same at master.  So while each process can create an appropriate subarray type, master can only have one.  I did get this to work for arrays of all the same type but not for arrays of different types.  The ordering in the global array would be correct but there would be gaps.

Comment: You're right that the single recvtype is what kills you - unlike Alltoall, there is no Gatherw variant that has multiple types. I think you could cope with varying m1 and m2 if n2-n1 were constant: create a type with a block of n2-n1+1 elements and a trailing gap that ensures the extent is the size of the entire first dimension, then use Gatherv with appropriate displacements and counts of m2-m1+1. Strangely, your pattern would be easy if you were writing directly to file using MPI-IO, but it's not easy if you're gathering to a master.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear about all the details of your setup, but here is a simple solution that illustrates how to do it under the restriction that the work divides exactly among processes, i.e. nlines is a multiple of size.

In this case, the pattern at the master is a simple vector (i.e. a 2D subarray). The only trick is to resize the vector appropriately so that the contributions line up correctly at the receiver. You don't need to use Gatherv - each process sends a bunch of doubles and the master receives a single vector from everyone.

The solution for the general case depends on how you split up the data when it does not divide exactly. You could use this solution if all the processes have the same amount of data except for the last one who has less data, but you pad out the data on the last process so that it can send and receive the same amount of data as the rest (including some dummy data).

I initialise the data so that, for example, at step 3 the values of the lines distributed across processes are 301, 302, 303, ... 300+nlines. If I run on 4 processes with 12 lines and 4 steps then the output looks correct:

laptop:~$ mpiexec -n 4 ./gather2d

```
 rank, mystart, myend            2           7           9
 rank, mystart, myend            1           4           6
 rank, mystart, myend            0           1           3
 rank, mystart, myend            3          10          12
           1         101         201         301         401
           2         102         202         302         402
           3         103         203         303         403
           4         104         204         304         404
           5         105         205         305         405
           6         106         206         306         406
           7         107         207         307         407
           8         108         208         308         408
           9         109         209         309         409
          10         110         210         310         410
          11         111         211         311         411
          12         112         212         312         412
```

Here's the code:

```
program gather2d

  use mpi

  implicit none

  integer :: nlines, nsteps
  integer :: comm, rank, size, ierr, arraytype, arraytyperesized
  integer :: mystart, myend
  integer :: i, j
  integer :: dblesize

  double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: B_lines

  integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) lb, extent

  comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD

  nlines = 12
  nsteps = 4

  call MPI_Init(ierr)

  call MPI_Comm_size(comm, size, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_rank(comm, rank, ierr)

  mystart = nlines/size * rank + 1
  myend   = nlines/size * (rank+1)

  write(*,*) 'rank, mystart, myend ', rank, mystart, myend

  if (rank == 0) then

    allocate(B_lines(1:nlines, 0:nsteps))

  else

    allocate(B_lines(mystart:myend, 0:nsteps))

  end if

  do i = mystart, myend
     do j = 0, nsteps

        B_lines(i,j) = i+100*j

     end do
  end do

  call MPI_Type_vector(nsteps+1, myend-mystart+1, nlines, &
                       MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, arraytype, ierr)

  call MPI_Type_size(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dblesize, ierr)

  lb = 0
  extent = (myend-mystart+1)*dblesize

  call MPI_Type_Create_resized(arraytype, lb, extent, arraytyperesized, ierr)

  call MPI_Type_commit(arraytyperesized, ierr)

  if (rank == 0) then

     call MPI_Gather(MPI_IN_PLACE, (nsteps+1)*(myend-mystart+1), &
                     MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                     B_lines, 1, arraytyperesized, 0, comm, ierr)

  else

     call MPI_Gather(B_lines, (nsteps+1)*(myend-mystart+1), &
                     MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                     B_lines, 1, arraytyperesized, 0, comm, ierr)

  end if

  if (rank == 0) then

     do i = 1, nlines
        write(*,*) (int(B_lines(i,j)), j = 0, nsteps)
     end do

  end if

  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program gather2d
```

Comment: I'm trying to generate the code in an arbitrary way.  Basically I want a subroutine where root has a global array and everyone else in the communicator has some part of it that runs from n1:n2 and m1:m2.  Mostly I'm trying to understand the subarray type.